# add an association to the an entity to model a message thread means?

Tags: multithreading, hibernate

I was going through getting started document [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic-config) given on Hibernate website. I am just starting to learn t, there is one section with the name "Take it further!". They mentioned that "With help of the Developer Guide, add an association to the Event entity to model a message thread."

Can somebody put some light on what a message thread is. Please make me undrestand what exactly is needed. Is it they are asking for message passing through Thread in Java one something else.Is it something similar to this **Inter-Thread Communication**.

Please suggest if you want me to read something. I am not clear about the requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any accepted answer. Please accept/Upvote answers if they are useful.

Comment: I think it's got nothing to do with Thread programming. I think "model a message thread" here means create a relationship between Event(s), like a "last event", "next event" relationship between Event. So basically it's an exercise about association between entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As told In the Community API [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/quickstart/en-US/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic-config).

`With help of the Developer Guide, add an association to the Event entity to model a message thread.`

**What is been told there is to work on the example given, And add some relations ships to the `Event` entity.** Read the documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html) or an example [here](http://jyops.blogspot.com/2011/03/hibernate-mapping-example.html) on how to do it.

From the documentation:**And you need to expand it.**

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
session.beginTransaction();
session.save( new Event( "Our very first event!", new Date() ) );
session.save( new Event( "A follow up event", new Date() ) );
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.close();
```

**It has nothing to do with the Threading in Java.**.

Comment: yes. Adding relationship is fine.But still message thread what it is?